# How to run this function on my GPU? (python)

Tags: python, optimization, numba

Id like to speed up this program by using my gpu:

```
import string
from numba.typed import List
from numba import jit, cuda
import time

alp = string.ascii_letters


@jit(target="gpu")
def test():
    for i in alp:
        for x in alp:
            print(i + x)

def speedTest():
    start_time = time.time()
    test()
    print(time.time() - start_time)
```

But everytime I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    speed()
  File "F:/Script Projects#/Tester.py", line 17, in speed
    test()
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\dispatcher.py", line 40, in __call__
    return self.compiled(*args, **kws)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\compiler.py", line 758, in __call__
    kernel = self.specialize(*args)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\compiler.py", line 769, in specialize
    kernel = self.compile(argtypes)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\compiler.py", line 784, in compile
    kernel = compile_kernel(self.py_func, argtypes,
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_lock.py", line 32, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: compile_kernel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'boundscheck'
```

I want to later replace the 'print()' with something else but for now I just need that to work.
It works with nopython mode instead of target="gpu".
Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the actual problem you want to solve ("something else")? You may be able to use a python GPU library for it, but note that Numba.cuda does not currently support strings.